# Revealing & Switching Between Hidden HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, html

I've read through a lot of tickets like this question but can't seem to get what I want to work. So I've had to ask this one.

I have 2 forms on a HTML page and 2 buttons. 
Both forms are hidden using inline styling: style="display:none;"

What I want to do is reveal form 1 with button 1 and hide form 2, and button 2 to hide form 1 and show form 2. 
Here is button 1:

```
<button type="button" id="button7">Click Here If your Serial Number is 549999 or Below</button>
```

Here is button 2:

```
<button type="button" id="button8">Click Here If your Serial Number is 550000 or Above</button>
```

This is form 1:

```
<form name="lowsearch" id="lowsearch" method="post" action="action.html" target="formresponse" style="display:none;">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="command" VALUE="search">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="file" VALUE="Repair_Project/R&S2Web.db">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="database" VALUE="Old_Serial">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="searchfields" VALUE="S_Serial_No;S_Description">
        <p><b>Please enter your Serial Number</b></p>
            <input TYPE="text" size="10" name="S_Serial_No" id="S_Serial_No" required>
        <p><input TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="b1" id="SUMBIT" VALUE="Find Device" class="buttonText"></p>
</form>
```

This is form 2:

```
    <form name="highsearch" id="highsearch" method="post" action="action.html" target="formresponse" style="display:none;">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="command" VALUE="search">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="file" VALUE="Repair_Project/R&S2Web.db">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="database" VALUE="Serial">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="searchfields" VALUE="S_Serial_No;S_Description">
        <p><b>Please enter your Serial Number</b></p>
            <input TYPE="text" size="10" name="S_Serial_No" id="S_Serial_No" required>
        <p><input TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="b1" id="SUMBIT" VALUE="Find Device" class="buttonText"></p>
</form>
```

My issue is I don't know how to finish the Javascript to get the desired affect.

```
<script>
function func(a) {
var el;
if(a === 1) {
    el = document.getElementById("lowsearch");
}
if(a === 2) {
    el = document.getElementById("highsearch");
}
document.getElementById('button7').onclick = function () {
    func(1);
};
document.getElementById('button8').onclick = function() {
    func(2)
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is change the `style` property on the forms based on which one you want to show/hide. Inside the `if` blocks in your `func` function, you can set the property display values.

```
function func(a) {
    if(a === 1) {
        document.getElementById("lowsearch").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("highsearch").style.display = "none";
    }
    if(a === 2) {
        document.getElementById("lowsearch").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("highsearch").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

You can view an example of it working at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thetimbanks/mzvkxr7d/

Comment: Thanks Tim!
I must be missing something because I still can't get it working. 
I can see your example working perfectly and it's exactly what I want to happen. 
Maybe I'm putting the script in the wrong place. It's in the header with script tags.

Comment: Worked it now. :) Needed to put the script in the body. 
Thanks again Tim!

Comment: Glad it worked for you Chris! As you found out, this code will execute as soon as it is loaded. Having it it in your <head> tag will cause it to execute before the body is loaded. Moving it to the bottom of your body tag will ensure the body has loaded before the script is run.